# How do I split a particular string value?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, slice

I have two types of strings like...

```
var a = "23 years 08months 12 days";
var b = "5 years 8 months 1 days";
```

I want to reduce this string like ...

```
"23 years 08 months" 
"5 years 8 months"
```

I tried using replace and split like this...

```
var a = "23 years 03 months 24 days";
var b = a.replace(/ /g,'')
var c;
if(b.length < 23){c = b.slice(0,13) }
```

But its not constant way to do! any suggestion please?

Comment: @Sahish best option will be to use https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I thought Moment.js was for formatting dates, not splitting strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following Regex:

```
(?<=months).*
```

(?<=) is a positive look-behind that will make sure everything you match with the .* will be preceded with months.

Which would result in JS:

```
a.replace(/(?<=months).*/g,'');
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick, without using regex

```
var s = 'months';
var a = '23 years 03 months 24 days';

a = a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf(s) + s.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example, based on your comment where you indicate that you want to cut off at months:

```js
var a = "23 years 08 months 12 days";
var b = "5 years 8 months 1 days";

console.log(a.split("months")[0]+" months");
console.log(b.split("months")[0]+"months");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could search and replace year and month values.

```js
function yearMonth(s) {
    return s.replace(/^(\d+)\s*years\s*(\d+)\s*months(.*)/, '$1 years $2 months');
}

console.log(yearMonth("23 years 08months 12 days"));
console.log(yearMonth("5 years 8 months 1 days"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split on `months` and append the string `months` to the first value of the split array:

```js
var a = "23 years 08 months 12 days";
var b = "5 years 8 months 1 days";
var res = a.split('months')[0] + 'months';
console.log(res);
res = b.split('months')[0] + 'months';
console.log(res);
```

You can also use the substring approach:

```js
var a = "23 years 08 months 12 days";
var b = "5 years 8 months 1 days";

var res = a.substring(0, a.indexOf('months')) + 'months';
console.log(res);

var res = b.substring(0, b.indexOf('months')) + 'months';
console.log(res);
```